# When is $r^n+p\mathbb{Z}=(r+p\mathbb{Z})^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, integers

Given $r, p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$.

Set $r^n+p\mathbb{Z}:=\{r^n+pm:m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $(r+p\mathbb{Z})^n=\{\prod_{i=1}^n(r+pm_i): m_1,\dots, m_n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Clearly, $(r+p\mathbb{Z})^n\subseteq r^n+p\mathbb{Z}$. What are conditions for $r,p,n$ such that $r^n+p\mathbb{Z}=(r+p\mathbb{Z})^n$? For example, when $r=0$ and $p>1$ this holds iff $n=1$.